# Can we say 'I haven't seen (someone) for days' to mean 'I never saw (someone) before'?

Tags: grammar

The title is clear, I suppose. This question appeared when I saw someone who's a native English commented something like this:

> We'd have to ask an alien and I haven't seen one **for days**.

In my opinion, the phrase *for days* is quite the same as *for ages* or *for a long time*. That makes me think, it's supposedly used when someone **has seen** it before. For instance:

> After the divorce, I haven't seen her **for days**

In my example above, I believe, it means I've known my ex-wife and I've met her, but after the divorce I haven't seen her for ages *in a long time interval*.

That would be different, if the case is I never saw her that means we were not even married. Like when I say:

> Never did I meet your daughter, Paul. Is she beautiful?

That means that I truly never saw Paul's daughter before.

My final question, are those sentences (in the title) **equivalent**? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use 'for days, weeks, months, years' (etc) to mean a period of time for which it is sensible to use the term chosen. For example, 'for days' means 'a small number of days'. The maximum is not exactly defined, but if the time was more than 14 days we might decide to say 'for weeks'. It has been raining for hours, my dog has been missing for days, my mother has been away for weeks, that supermarket has been closed for months, I haven't driven a car for years.

I know of two alternative US slang meanings, in US gay culture - an exclamation of surprise or shock 'You won the sweepstake? *For days!*' and one arising out of Black culture in the 1960s, meaning 'a lot of something' - e.g. 'A certain singer has a lovely face, great figure, and legs for days'. I do not believe that either of these meanings is intended.

The remark about not having seen an alien 'for days' is **a joke**. Nobody has seen any aliens. The joke pretends that aliens exist (when everyone knows that they have not so far been found). Consider: to know what my brother is planning, you'd need a mind-reader, and I haven't seen one of those for weeks.

Comment: Well, your answer is undeniably better than mine but about the alien part. In the example maybe the person was in another kind of world?

Comment: @SorryI'mDumb - Why assume that? There is no evidence, and that type of joke, based on impossibility, is common enough. You asked me to dig a 30 metre deep pit in two hours. Well, I'd need a Martian atomic-powered laser excavator to do that, and when I called the hire company they were all being used by customers.

Comment: ;-; I didn't say it was a fact, just the example being a kind of a metaphor?

Comment: It's a common type of joke, and often jokes depend on metaphor and counterfactualness.

Comment: Oh, well I get it now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: So, just to clarify - you would be unlikely to say "I haven't seen her [my ex-wife] for days" - you would only say it about someone you usually meet frequently.

Comment: You could say it if you saw her days rather than weeks, months, or years ago, no matter how often you usually meet.

Comment: @KateBunting - I mean - if a police officer said "Your wife was murdered last night, Mr Harvey, when did you last see her?", and I last saw her on Wednesday last week (nine days ago), I might well say "I last saw her days ago!". I might not 'meet' her frequently; I might have seen her out of a bus window.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - The OP asked about using "I haven't seen her for days" of a wife divorced a long time ago. I was intending to explain that you wouldn't use _days_ in this scenario, but _months_ or _years_, as you say in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> We'd have to ask an alien and I haven't seen one for days.

This type of joke is called a '[bait and switch](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BaitAndSwitch)' by comedians, or formally called a *paraprosdokian*, if you want to dig into it more:

> A type of setup where a character leads the audience or other characters into thinking they are going to say or do something, but says or does something unexpected. This is usually a joke, and if the punch line of the joke causes the first part to take on a new meaning (e.g., "I just flew in from Chicago, and boy are my arms tired"), it is technically called a "paraprosdokian."

So in the example from TV tropes if someone says "I just flew in from Chicago...", you're picturing them on an aeroplane & expect them to tell you something about their flight (it was really busy/delayed/the food was no good), but then they switch it for the absurd mental image of them flapping instead ("boy, are my arms tired!").

It's the same format with the line you quoted:

> We'd have to ask an alien...

You're expecting them to finish with "but of course they don't exist".

Here are some more examples from Wikipedia:

- "I've had a perfectly wonderful evening, but this wasn't it." — Groucho Marx
- "I haven't slept for ten days, because that would be too long." — Mitch Hedberg
- "I don't belong to an organized political party. I'm a Democrat." — Will Rogers

Normally these usages are playing on multiple variants of meaning for the same words — e.g. "I haven't slept for days" is a common way of saying "it's been days since I slept" (interval), but the 'bait-and-switch' turns it into duration. "Organized political party" is a phrase we use to talk about mainstream parties that are registered in some way, but he turns it around that the party is in disarray.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are correct about "someone has seen it before."

Both **for days** and **for ages** are completely different, sure they are similar but in some cases. The two sentences can be different since we can use *for days* when, for example, after my friend left the party, I haven't seen him *for days* (This could either mean for a *few days* or as you say it, *for ages*).

More examples,

> After we had a heated argument last week, I haven't seen Chris **for days**.

- We can say this means *few days*.

and

> After I graduated college, I haven't seen Jennifer **for ages**.

- While we can say this as in a *few years*.

It just depends on the sentence. While **for days** and **for ages** is the same, *for ages* is a recurring activity over a *longer* period of time.

"Never did I" indicates shock, astonishment, flabbergasted, etc.

Comment: Thank you, and related to the question, did the native in the first quote use *for days* correctly? Can the usage of *for days* after *I haven't seen (someone)* mean something that he never encountered before?

Comment: Assuming that the "alien" referred to is an extraterrestrial, the speaker who said he hadn't seen an alien for days was using humorous understatement. "for days" is not equivalent to "ever", except in such a joke.

Comment: We'd have to ask an alien and I haven't seen one for days? If yes, I'm not sure since it can either mean both but seeing the word aliens, it must be for ages. For example, I haven't seen Jake *for days*. No, he has already encountered that "something" if he said "for days" since reading the sentence, you can assume he has already seen it, because he is mentioning it.

Comment: Oh, it's joke? ;-;

Comment: Even though it's fictional, using *for days* should mean he saw it before. Otherwise, if he didn't see the alien then *for days* wouldn't be used and the sentence would be like this, **I haven't seen an alien before**.

Comment: @SorryI'mDumb your last comment is what exactly I want as an answer. Thank you so much! And by the way, I've upvoted your answer, but seemed like someone had downvoted your answer. Just want you to know that you have my upvote. Thanks btw.

Comment: Happy to help, and yes. I saw it in the edit history :)

Comment: " For days is an idiomatic phrase that refers to an overabundance of a particular trait, attribute, or object. The concept is that someone has so much of something that it appears to last "for days." This is complete nonsense.

Comment: Well, that hurt. I'll change it.